# Select unique product based on minimum order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The objective is to select unique product when the order is minimum.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order': [1,2,3],
                   'Product':['Apple','Apple','Orange'],
                   'Metric': ['20 x 2 g','20 x 2 g','23 x 2 g']})
df

  Order Product Metric
0   1   Apple   20 x 2 g
1   2   Apple   20 x 2 g
2   3   Orange  23 x 2 g
```

**Expected Output:**

 To select Apple, Metric 20 x 2g at order number 1 as its order is minimum.

```
    Order   Product Metric
0   1   Apple   20 x 2 g
1   3   Orange  23 x 2 g
```

Kindly let me know your view. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.sort_values('Order').groupby('Metric',as_index=False).first()
```

or [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.sort_values('Order').drop_duplicates('Metric',keep = 'first')
```

**Output:**

```
    Order   Product Metric
0   1   Apple   20 x 2 g
1   3   Orange  23 x 2 g
```

Comment: Thanks ansev, but it is not showing the expected output. Kindly check it once. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, pleas echeck now:) Tell me if you can accpet my answer